# Como usar o ParamConverter dentro do controller ou em serviço

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2

O [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) é uma anotação que uso constantemente no [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) para recuperar os dados enviados já em objeto, assim o parse é feito automático, bastando, no meu caso, adicionar comentário no método do respectivo controller e ao receber o parâmetro o symfony ele já me envia o objeto, já fazendo o reflection e parse necessário. Um simples.

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="SensioBlogBundle:Post")
 */
public function showAction(Post $post)
{
}
```

E a variável $post já é recebida como objeto e totalmente populada, porém o que eu preciso é algo do tipo:

```
/**
 * 
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, $classname, $entity)
{
    $post = new ParamConverter(array('class'=> $classname));
}
```

Isso porque eu gostaria de implementar um CRUD genérico e nesse caso eu não sei qual a classe que virá, pode ser qualquer classe, alguém sabe como seria possível fazer dessa forma?

Comment: Vou dar +1 porque sou um admirador do [tag:symfony]

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria da seguinte forma.

Suponhamos que você tenha as seguintes rotas genéricas no seu CRUD:

```
GET    /{type}             // lista os objetos de um determinado tipo
GET    /{type}/new         // exibe o formulário para criação de um objeto
GET    /{type}/{id}        // exibe um objeto
GET    /{type}/{id}/edit   // exibe o formulário para edição de um objeto
GET    /{type}/{id}/delete // exibe o formulário para exclusão de um objeto
POST   /{type}             // cria um objeto
PUT    /{type}/{id}        // edita um objeto
DELETE /{type}/{id}        // exclui um objeto
```

Portanto, esses seriam os métodos do seu *controller*:

```
public function listAction(Request $request, $type)
{
}

public function newAction(Request $request, $type)
{
}

public function getAction(Request $request, $type, $id)
{
}

public function getEditAction(Request $request, $type, $id)
{
}

public function getDeleteAction(Request $request, $type, $id)
{
}

public function postAction(Request $request, $type)
{
}

public function putAction(Request $request, $type, $id)
{
}

public function deleteAction(Request $request, $type, $id)
{
}
```

(ps: eu gosto de dividir minhas actions para que cada uma tenha o mínimo de responsabilidades, você pode querer desenhar o seu sistema de outra maneira.)

Para que eu possa obter um método ou uma coleção de objetos, eu buscaria um repositório cuja entidade está mapeada com o valor recebido na URL:

```
private function getRepositoryName($type)
{
    $mappings = [
        'user'    => AppBundle\Entity\User::class,
        'item'    => AppBundle\Entity\Item::class,
        'order'   => AppBundle\Entity\Order::class,
        'address' => AppBundle\Entity\Order::class,
        'phone'   => AppBundle\Entity\Order::class,
    ]

    returns $mappings[$type];
}

$repository = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository($this->getRepositoryName($type));

$entidade  = $repository->find($id); // para buscar um único objeto
$entidades = $repository->findAll(); // para buscar uma coleção de objetos
```

A partir disso, com o objeto em mãos (ou uma coleção deles), basta usar o objeto `Request` recebido para processar uma eventual postagem de dados via HTTP.

Você também pode usar o padrão acima para buscar formulários registrados no service container, já que dessa forma você só precisaria do ID de serviço deles. Dessa forma seu CRUD já fica bem genérico. :)

Comment: Obrigado rodrigo, mas não é esse o objetivo, o esqueleto do CRUD eu até tenho, para recuperar um objeto pelo id, pode ser usado o find básico mesmo, porém o objeto é recuperar os dados enviados e converter para o objeto, como o ParamConverter faz por exemplo quando você envia um JSON por post, ele consegue mapear o objeto de acordo com a classe que eu especificar na notação.